# Using Template with Typeahead in UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an AngularJS app. My app has a plunker that can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkXpPMwcCq5ytLRO0ILN?p=preview). This app has a service that I made for another project. That service looks like this:

```
myApp.service('myService', ['$http', '$timeout', '$q', function($http, $timeout, $q) {
  this.getResults = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var results = [];
    results.push({ name: 'Alpha', id:1, description:'The first' });
    results.push({ name: 'Bravo', id:2, description:'The second' });
    results.push({ name: 'Charlie', id:3, description:'The third' });

    deferred.resolve(results);

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I'm trying to use the Typeahead control in [UI Bootstrap framework](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I successfully have the basics wired up. However, I cannot figure out how to get the custom result templates to work. I do not understand where they are pulling the property values from. I'm just trying to create a template that shows the name and description field. When the item is selected, I want to show the name in the text box. My plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkXpPMwcCq5ytLRO0ILN?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/VJFx436Tsew9unXWNQsJ?p=preview

1.Here you setting up template name `typeahead-template-url="result.html"`
so id of your template script has to be `"result.html"`

2. To access data from your match model in template you need to use `match.model` prefix.

   ```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="result.html">
   <a>
     <div><h6>{{match.model.name}}<h6>< /div>
     <div><p>{{match.model.description}}</p></div>
   </a>
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Cool! I noticed when you click an item in the popup list it doesn't appear in the text box though.